# Why function Javascript doesn't execute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, ajax

I need to execute a function named "send()" who contain an ajax request.
This function is in ajax.js (included in )
The Ajax success update the src of my image.

This function work well, I don't think that it is the problem

But when I load the page, send() function is not executed :o I don't understand why.

After loading, I click on a button, and the function work ! (the code of the button is not in the code below)

You can see the HTML code, my function below, and node JS code. Thanks for your help.

Since your answer, the problem is now : POST http://localhost:3000/index/gen/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

The script is executed, the problem was that some data were not initialized (Jquery sliders)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Génération</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" title="super style" href="./styles/feuille.css">
    <script src="./script/ajax.js"></script>
    </head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <body>
    <img src="images/map.jpg" class="superbg" alt="Carte du monde"/>

    <div id="main">
        <header>
            <div id="titre">  
                <h1>Generator</h1>
            </div>
        </header>                       

        <img id="image" src="" alt="Map">

        <script>
        send(); //in file ajax.js included in head
        alert($("#image").attr('src'));
        </script>

    <footer>
        Copyright CLEBS 2017, tous droits réservés.
    </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here send function

```
function send(){
        var data = {"some data useless for my question"};
        alert("i'm in send() function");
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index/gen/', //(It's node JS)
        data: data,
        success : function(j){
            var img = document.getElementById('image');
            img.src = j;
        },
        complete : function(j){
            },
        });       
    }
```

Node JS code

```
app.post('/index/gen/',urlencodedParser, function (req,res){                    
    const { spawn } = require('child_process');
    const ls = spawn('./generateur/minigen.py', 
    req.session.donnees = ''
    ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        req.session.donnees+=data.toString();
    }); 
    ls.stderr.on('datas', (datas) => {
        console.log("Erreur"+`stderr: ${datas}`);
    });
    var options = {         //Encapsulation des données à envoyer
      mode: 'JSON',
      pythonOptions: ['-u'],
      scriptPath: './generateur',               //ligne du dessous c'est les valeurs saisies par l'utilisateur
      args: ["Some data useless for my question"]
    };
    pythonShell.run('generation.py', options, function (err, results) { //Make the map to be download 
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(req.session.donnees);
    });
}
})
```

Comment: can you post your JS code?

Comment: What is the sequence of events that lead to the Send() function being called?

Comment: what does the console tell you?

Comment: florian, try the updated edit in my answer

Comment: Send() send some data to node JS. 
Node Js call python, and python returns base64 image.
Node Js return Base64 to ajax request. Success Ajax request replace image src by base64 image

Comment: florain, did my edited answer work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no function named `send` in your code. You have a function named `envoi`. Change `function envoi()` to `function send()`  The hazards of multilingual coding!

**Edit: since you updated your answer, try this.**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    send();
    alert($("#image").attr('src'));
});
</script>
```

Comment: He mentions that "send()" exists in the included "ajax.js" script in his header.

Comment: @AaronFranco he also mentions he copied the function into the html so we can see it. `You can see the HTML code, and my function below`  Why would you downvote this? It could very well be the reason he is having an issue. Whew.

Comment: `alert("i'm in send() function");` Well seems @KayakinKoder is actually right

Comment: Sorry but this answer ignores the numerous problems with the code in the question. Especially the scoping issues and improperly placed JavaScript.

Comment: Well now the OP edited the question, that basically invalidates this answer.

Comment: I have update my question for to more precise
I will try  given solutions and I come back

Comment: @AaronFranco the code you wrote would likewise get kicked back by your boss in any production app for "numerous problems" and improperly placed javascript.

Comment: Console message : POST http://localhost:3000/index/gen/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 0):

You could use the onload Event.
This Event is called, wenn the page is loded completely and you can reach the send() function.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp

For instance:

```
<body onload="myFunction()"> 

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        send(); //in file ajax.js included in head
        alert($("#image").attr('src'));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Work ! Thanks you

Answer (score -1):

The format of the javascript is incorrect. The Scope of your solution needs to be managed with JQuery. If you simply want to call the function when the page loads, you can call the function inside the JQuery handler. Also, your syntax is not correct.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Génération</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" title="super style" href="./styles/feuille.css">


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="./script/ajax.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
    <img src="images/map.jpg" class="superbg" alt="Carte du monde"/>

    <div id="main">
        <header>
            <div id="titre">  
                <h1>Generator</h1>
            </div>
        </header>                       

        <img id="image" src="" alt="Map">

    <footer>
        Copyright CLEBS 2017, tous droits réservés.
    </footer>
     <script>
      $(function(){
         send(); //in file ajax.js included in head
         //  alert($("#image").attr('src')); <-- won't update inline due to async ajax
      })
     </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, the image tag alert should be updated in the Async callback.

```
  var data = {"some data useless for my question"}
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index/gen/',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json",
        complete: function(j) {
         $("#image").attr('src', j);
        }
    });
```

Also be aware that you want JQuery to load before your custom JavaScript. I'm not sure where you are calling Envoi, but this code should help you. It will trigger the "send()" function when the page loads. Also, script tags should be included in the Head tag.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I will try and tell you if it works

Comment: Thanks @florian, please select my answer if this works for you :) I hope it helps you better understand the scoping issue in JS page loading using JQuery.

Comment: So, it doesn't change anything, the function is not executed.
Envoi() it's in french, that meens send(), it's now translated

Comment: Sorry but this answer ignores the numerous problems with the code in the question. First, your $.ajax call is missing `dataType`. Second, you should not be using <script> to execute js in an html file. Instead, the js should be moved to an external file. Third, definitely should not be relying on `https://code.jquery.com/` to send us the jquery source; if their site goes down, ours does to. Instead, use a package manager to pull in dependencies and bundle them up.

Comment: @KayakinKoder we are not building a production environment, just fixing the code in question, so your comments are not valid, but thanks anyway. Florian I updated my Send function above, if that fails, it could be your Node.js script that is causing the issue.

Comment: Console message : POST http://localhost:3000/index/gen/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: That typically means your server is offline or getting an internal server error. Do you see errors in the Node.js Console output?

Comment: Don't worry, it's ok now, Thanks guys !